# Why is the same Node.js process using much more memory on my computer than on my coworkers' computers?

Tags: node.js, memory

In our project at work (https://github.com/SparkDevNetwork/Rock), we run some custom-made scripts that watch the files and re-compile them when they change. You can do this by going into the Rock.JavaScript.Obsidian and Rock.JavaScript.Obsidian.Blocks folders and running `npm run watch` (assuming you've installed dependencies).

When I run them (and let them finish) I see one of them using over 3GB of memory and the other is using over 2GB.

My coworkers who have similar Windows 11 machines with 32GB of memory only use about 1.5GB for both of them combined.

Why is my computer using more than 3x the memory for the same processes?